# How to use a similitude to find a locus?

Tags: geometry

We have two points $A$, $B$ and a similitude $s$ with center $\Omega$ such that $s(A)=A'$ and $s(B)=B'$.

I am trying to determinate the locus of points $M$ of the plane such that the points $A,B,M, M'=s(M)$ are concyclic.
It happens that this locus is a circular cubic but do you know a way to demonstrate this fact ?
Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: How did yo obtain the curve ?

Comment: It's a macro-construction someone made with from Cabri II.

Comment: But how do you know it is a circular cubic ?

Comment: The information was given in the exercice.

Comment: What is the course chapter about ?

Comment: You can find the equation by writing the concyclicity condition, that expresses that the vectors $(x^2+y^2,x,y,1)$ corresponding to the four points are linearly dependent (zero determinant). At the same time, the coordinates of the image of M are an affine function of the latter.

Comment: The exercice was proposed as part of a course on plane transformations. The exercice itself is inspired by a problem of Michel Bataille (the American Mathematical Monthly).

Comment: Oh OK, thank you for that hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

WLOG, $\Omega$ is the origin and the similitude can be written as $(x,y)\to(ax+by,bx-ay)$.

Then the requested locus is

$$\begin{vmatrix}
(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)&ax+by&bx-ay&1\\
x^2+y^2&x&y&1\\
x_A^2+y_A^2&x_A&y_A&1\\
x_B^2+y_B^2&x_B&y_B&1\\
\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

Obviously we can cancel out a term $x^2+y^2$, and the resulting determinant is a cubic polynomial in $x,y$, of the form

$$(x^2+y^2)L(x,y)+M(x,y)=0$$ where $L$ and $M$ are two first-degree polynomials.